# EOFException in using Universal Image Loader

Tags: android, image, android-studio, adapter, universal-image-loader

I am using Universal Image Loader Library in android. Its working perfect, But I am getting following error.

```
E/ImageLoader﹕ null
java.io.EOFException
        at libcore.io.Streams.readAsciiLine(Streams.java:203)
        at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponseHeaders(HttpEngine.java:579)
        at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:827)
        at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:283)
        at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:497)
        at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromNetwork(BaseImageDownloader.java:117)
        at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStream(BaseImageDownloader.java:88)
        at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.downloadImage(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:291)
        at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryCacheImageOnDisk(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:274)
        at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryLoadBitmap(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:230)
        at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.run(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:136)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Following is my code in Application class.

```
 DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
            .cacheOnDisk(true)
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.mipmap.fico_not_found)
            .showImageOnFail(R.mipmap.fico_not_found)
            .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300))
            .build();

    ImageLoaderConfiguration config1 = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
            .memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache())
            .diskCacheSize(100 * 1024 * 1024)
            .build();

    this.imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    imageLoader.init(config1);
```

And I have use the following code in my adapter class

```
 imageLoader = ((Application)context.getApplicationContext()).getImageLoader();
imageLoader.displayImage(Utils.IMAGE_URL + image_name,parentViewHolder.logo);
```

Does anyone got such error? Any help regarding this will be appreciated.

Comment: why use UIL libaray? They no longer maintain that library. Try using glide or Picasso.

Comment: Piccaso :http://www.picasso.fr/us/picasso_page_index.php                                            
Glide :https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Comment: @ZeeshanShabbir- I was using picasso, but there is no way to manage cache so I am using UIL.

Comment: are you fetching image url's using httpConnection ?

Comment: @AkshayTilekar- yes

Answer (score 0):

This was not a well documented answer. It appears in some of the newer versions of android, there is a bug with recycled url connections. To fix this (although there may be some performance issues), you needed to add:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK != null && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 13) {
    urlConnect.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close"); //set URL connection property
}
```